# detect duplicates on rows and remove class when value is changed HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day,

I have a table that can detect duplicated row on blur and I already implemented it, the code was from [stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6470/mark-rows-with-identical-values-in-a-table) and its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Kcas2/), but Im confused on how to remove the class 'duplicate' when I change the value into a unique one.

heres my html

```
 <table class="table" id="FS-table">
 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="10%">Format Code</th>
                        <th width="60%">Account Title</th>
                        <th width="30%">Accound Number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="rowId-1" type="text" class="fs-format-code form-control"></td>
                            <td><span class="accound-desc">Cash on Hand</span></td>
                            <td><span class="account-number">11110</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="rowId-2" type="text" class="fs-format-code form-control"></td>
                            <td><span class="accound-desc">Petty Cash Fund</span></td>
                            <td><span class="account-number">11120</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="rowId-3" type="text" class="fs-format-code form-control"></td>
                            <td><span class="accound-desc">CCash in Bank</span></td>
                            <td><span class="account-number">11110</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input  id="rowId-4" type="text" class="fs-format-code form-control"></td>
                            <td><span class="accound-desc">Accounts Receivable - Trade</span></td>
                            <td><span class="account-number">11320</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="rowId-5" type="text" class="fs-format-code form-control"></td>
                            <td><span class="accound-desc">Allowance for Bad Debts</span></td>
                            <td><span class="account-number">11110</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

and my js:

```
$('input.fs-format-code').on('blur', function(){
        var tableRows = $("#FS-table tbody tr");

        tableRows.each(function(n){
        var FsInput = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code');

        var id = FsInput.attr('id');
        var row = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').val();


        tableRows.each(function(n){               
            var id2 = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').attr('id');
            // console.log("id2: "+id2 +", "+"id :"+id);

            if(id2 != id){
                var row2 = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').val();
                console.log("row2 :"+row2 + ", row :"+row);    
                if (row2 == row)
                {
                   $(this).addClass('duplicate');
                }
                else{
                  //  $(this).removeClass('duplicate');
                }
              }
           });
       });

});
```

if I add the else statement it will just remove again the added 'duplicate' class, How Am I gonna do it properly so that it can properly detect duplicate values or not ? thanks for your help. If you find my question hard to understand, please let me know so I can edit it right away. Have a Good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all of the duplicate classes at the start of the function, and then in your inner loop you could exclude all the ones marked duplicate:

```
$('input.fs-format-code').on('blur', function(){
        var tableRows = $("#FS-table tbody tr");

        /*-- Remove All Duplicate Classes --*/
        tableRows.filter(".duplicate").removeClass("duplicate");

        tableRows.each(function(n){
            var FsInput = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code');

            var id = FsInput.attr('id');
            var row = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').val();

            /* -- Exclude Duplicates -- */
            tableRows.not(".duplicate").each(function(n){               
                var id2 = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').attr('id');
                // console.log("id2: "+id2 +", "+"id :"+id);

                if(id2 != id){
                    var row2 = $(this).find('input.fs-format-code').val();
                    console.log("row2 :"+row2 + ", row :"+row);    
                    if (row2 == row)
                    {
                       $(this).addClass('duplicate');
                    }
                }
           });
       });
});
```

It doubt it is the most efficient method, but it is probably one of the simplest modifications to your current code.

Update Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kcas2/70/

Answer (score 0):

In order to not change your code,
There is a trick to determine witch input is same as witch another, just change if/else of your code like this:

```
if (row2 == row && row2 != '' && row != '')
{
     $(this).addClass('duplicate'+id);
}
 else{
     $(this).removeClass('duplicate'+id);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yq72tr6b/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Masoud but when I test your jsfiddle link its kinda buggy, but Thanks for your effort and the thought! :)